# Error en constructor al enviar dato de un Jframe a otro Jframe

Tags: java, jframe

Tengo un `.java` para loguearme en una aplicación y quiero que si el logueo es correcto, **envíe el usuario insertado al otro `.java`** que será la interfaz principal.

He probado a insertar un `JoptionPane` para ver si recoge el dato correctamente, y sí lo hace.

**Código JFrame Logueo:**

```
} else if(Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password).size()>0) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido "+usuario+"!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            this.dispose();
            Index i = new Index(usuario);
            i.setVisible(true);
```

**Código JFrame interfaz a donde pasamos el dato:**

```
     public Index(String usuario) {
            initComponents();
            label_usuario.setText("Sesión iniciada por "+usuario);
            ...
            ...
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Index().setVisible(true); //aquí el error, intuyo que sea por el constructor.
            }
        });
    }
```

El error lo tengo en:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Index().setVisible(true); //aquí el error, intuyo que sea por el constructor.
        }
    });
}
```

**Si ejecuto el programa desde el archivo de logueo sí me funciona correctamente** y se envía el dato pero en el **IDE Netbeans** me sale que el archivo interfaz principal me sale erróneo. Aquí el **error**: `new Index().setVisible(true);` -esperaba una variable en el constructor y no fue recibida, ¿es normal o se puede salvar el error en el archivo?

**¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?**

Comment: Si el constructor de la clase `Index` recibe un parámetro, no, no puedes llamarlo sin él. O te defines otro constructor sin parámetro y que no haga uso de ese parámetro, o tienes que cambiar la estructura de tu programa para tener siempre el usuario antes de crear el objeto de la clase `Index`.

Comment: La pregunta aquí sería: para qué necesitas un método `main()` en la clase `Index`? Estoy seguro de que ese es un código autogenerado por ti IDE y que en tu caso no necesitas. Por otro lado el comentario de @SuperG280 te indica el problema claramente.

Comment: Cierto, es un código autogenerado del Java Swing del IDE Netbeans. Al generar un Frame se crea ese código inborrable por defecto. @E.Betanzos